# Load data from Database to DropDownList using Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, knockout.js

I'm creating editing a variable length list using knockout. 
When I click Add Button, it will add a DropDownList and a TextBox to the screen. I've successfully load the data from database to DropDownList, but it always populating the data every time I clicked Add Button.

**Code:**

```
<div class="form-horizontal" data-bind="with: purchaseOrder">
    <h4>Purchase Order</h4>
    <hr />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="PurchaseOrderDate">PO Date</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: PurchaseOrderDate" placeholder="Purchase Order Date" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="InvoiceNo">Invoice No</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: InvoiceNo" placeholder="Invoice No" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Memo">Memo</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: Memo" placeholder="Enter Memo" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h4>Details</h4>
<hr />

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Qty Order</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: purchaseOrderDetails">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: AX_INVENTSUMs, optionsText: 'ITEMNAME', optionValue: 'ITEMID'"></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: QuantityOrder" placeholder="Enter Quantity Order">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href='#' data-bind=' click: $parent.removeItem'>X</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-bind='click: addItem'>Add Item</button>
</p>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var PurchaseOrder = function (purchaseOrder) {
                var self = this;

                self.PurchaseOrderID = ko.observable(purchaseOrder ? purchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderID : 0);
                self.PurchaseOrderDate = ko.observable(purchaseOrder ? purchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderDate : '');
                self.InvoiceNo = ko.observable(purchaseOrder ? purchaseOrder.InvoiceNo : '');
                self.Memo = ko.observable(purchaseOrder ? purchaseOrder.Memo : '');
            };

            var PurchaseOrderDetail = function (purchaseOrderDetail, items) {
                var self = this;

                self.PurchaseOrderDetailID = ko.observable(purchaseOrderDetail ? purchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrderDetailID : 0);
                self.PurchaseOrderID = ko.observable(purchaseOrderDetail ? purchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrderDetailID : 0);
                self.ItemID = ko.observable(purchaseOrderDetail ? purchaseOrderDetail.ItemID : 0);
                self.QuantityOrder = ko.observable(purchaseOrderDetail ? purchaseOrderDetail.QuantityOrder : 0);
                self.QuantityBonus = ko.observable(purchaseOrderDetail ? purchaseOrderDetail.QuantityBonus : 0);

                self.AX_INVENTSUMs = ko.observableArray(items);
            };

            var PurchaseOrderCollection = function () {
                var self = this;

                self.purchaseOrder = ko.observable(new PurchaseOrder());
                self.purchaseOrderDetails = ko.observableArray([new PurchaseOrderDetail()]);

                self.CashedArray = ko.observableArray([]);
                $.getJSON("/AX_INVENTSUM/GetAX_INVENTSUMs", null, function (data) {
                    var array = [];
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        array.push(value);
                    });
                    self.CashedArray(array);
                });

                self.addItem = function () {
                    self.purchaseOrderDetails.push(new PurchaseOrderDetail(null, self.CashedArray));
                };

                self.removeItem = function (purchaseOrderDetail) {
                    self.purchaseOrderDetails.remove(purchaseOrderDetail);
                };
            };

            ko.applyBindings(new PurchaseOrderCollection());
        });
    </script>
}
```

As you can see in the code above, how to make this occurs only once a time?

Comment: What does 'Add button' do? I suppose you create new PurchaseOrderDetail each time...

Comment: Second @Ivan. On a more general note, the code in your question can *not* be used to reproduce the problem, so we can't really help you (without resorting to guessing). Could you edit your answer and add more details? Perhaps complete it with a stack snippet to repro the issue?

Comment: @Ivan Yes it is, what I want is, maybe there is a variable to keep data from database, and when I click Add Button, I can use that variable to bind to dropdownlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must cache your list somewhere. I prefer to do it in something like parent view model. See bellow.

```
var OrderList = function(){
    var self = this;
    ...
    self.CashedArray = ko.observableArray(new Array());
    $.getJSON("/AX_INVENTSUM/GetAX_INVENTSUMs", null, function (data) {
        var array = [];
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            array.push(value);
        });
        self.CashedArray(array);
    });
    self.AddButtonClick = function (){
       var orderDetails = new PurchaseOrderDetail(self.CashedArray());
    };
};

var PurchaseOrderDetail = function (items) {
    var self = this;
    ...
    self.AX_INVENTSUMs = ko.observableArray(items);
};
```

Comment: The data is not loaded at page load and when I clicked Add Button I've got error `0x800a139e - Microsoft JScript runtime error: The argument passed when initializing an observable array must be an array, or null, or undefined.` I've updated the code.

Comment: @Willy, self.purchaseOrderDetails.push(new PurchaseOrderDetail(null, self.CashedArray)); - will not work. Use must change it to: self.purchaseOrderDetails.push(new PurchaseOrderDetail(null, self.CashedArray()));
self.CashedArray - is observable array, so u must pass to the child view model an 'array', but not an 'observableArray'

Comment: you're right, why the first dropdownlist is still empty when I load the page but the second dropdownlist (after I added one) is not empty?

Comment: @Willy, That's because of this line: 'self.purchaseOrderDetails = ko.observableArray([new PurchaseOrderDetail()]);' You may replace it   with 'self.purchaseOrderDetails = ko.observableArray([]);', and call self.addItem() right after data is loaded.

Comment: $.getJSON("/AX_INVENTSUM/GetAX_INVENTSUMs", null, function (data) {
                    var array = [];
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        array.push(value);
                    });
                    self.CashedArray(array);
                    self.addItem();
                });

Comment: Thanks @Ivan, if I replace it with `self.purchaseOrderDetails = ko.observableArray([]);` the detail is empty. I want to show 1 detail when the page is loaded. Is it possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65194/discussion-between-ivan-and-willy).